# Проблемы ноутбука под Windows

Tags: windows, ноутбук

Доброго времени суток! Есть ноутбук Lenovo IdeaPad 100-15IBY. Проблема заключается в том, что при закрытии крышки и переходе в ждущий режим, после её открытия (крышки) монитор остаётся черным. Также при попытке выключить или перезагрузить ноутбук, он зависает и возвращается к жизни только после принудительного выключения. Данные проблемы наблюдаются только на ОС Windows (7,10), на Ubuntu всё работает идеально. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: в драйверах конечно, попробуй загрузится в безопасном режиму и выполнить теже действия, посмотри что будет

Comment: А `Energy Manager and Flight Mode Driver for Windows` и всякие `intel management engine interface` установлены? Ну и БИОС на всякий случай шивнуть можно до последней модели.

Comment: Установка Energy Manager and Flight Mode Driver for Windows решила проблему. Благодарю!